# Get javascript array object from its name

Tags: javascript, arrays

In javascript I have an array of strings in which each string is name of another array.
How can I get each array object from its name?
In my example I need to get *cavaSel* array from its name which is contained in array *CaveTipo*

```
for (var i = 0; i < CaveTipo.length; i++) {
    var cavaSel = $(CaveTipo[i]);
    for (var t = 0; t < cavaSel.length; t++) {
        ///
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post sample for both the arrays.

Comment: @Massimiliano Revelli use `.each loop`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By 'name' I'll assume you mean 'identifier'.
For example: say you have 'identifier' `CaveTipo` to reference the following example array:

```
var CaveTipo=[ 'my_array_a'
             , 'my_array_b'
             , 'my_array_c'
             ]
; //end var
```

Above example array, contains strings which are the *identifiers* of other array's, for example:

```
var my_array_a=[ /* data */ ]
,   my_array_b=[ /* data */ ]
,   my_array_c=[ /* data */ ]
; //end var
```

Now in order to use the identifier (strings) in `CaveTipo` one should use bracket-notation on the object that holds the target-arrays: `namespace[/*identifier*/]` (instead of dot-notation).

If that namespace was global, then you'd use `window` (or `self`): `window[/*identifier*/]`.

```
var cavaSel, i, t;
for (i = 0; i < CaveTipo.length; i++) {
    cavaSel = window[ CaveTipo[i] ];
    for (t = 0; t < cavaSel.length; t++) {
        ///
    }
}
```

Now let's assume the array's are inside an object you created (in global):

```
var caveData={ my_array_a: [ /* data */ ]
             , my_array_b: [ /* data */ ]
             , my_array_c: [ /* data */ ]
             }
;

var cavaSel, i, t;
for (i = 0; i < CaveTipo.length; i++) {
    cavaSel = caveData[ CaveTipo[i] ];
    for (t = 0; t < cavaSel.length; t++) {
        ///
    }
}
```

This last approach is better in most cases since it either frees up namespace usage in global (for `my_array_X`) OR provides an identifier to the object within 'private' closures.

Comment: It doesn't work look in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/978xLwdk/ cavaSel is Undefined

Comment: Works perfectly: https://jsfiddle.net/978xLwdk/1/ Re-read my answer (regarding namespace/object) and look at the difference between your fiddle-**settings** and my fiddle-**settings**. You just wrapped the code inside a `onload`. The identifiers for 'my_array_X' were not in object `window` but in the 'private' closure of the onload-function (please do read the manuals for the tools (like jsfiddle) before you use them)... See this fiddle how it would have worked with your fiddle-**settings**: https://jsfiddle.net/978xLwdk/2/ (using object) or force to global: https://jsfiddle.net/978xLwdk/3/